# Jquery - Removing class on CHECKED/UNCHECKED RADIO BUTTONS

Tags: jquery, checked, unchecked

It's been 5 hours since i'm struggling with this, i searched up and down overhere. I'm trying to change the TABLE CELL BACKGROUND that contains a CHECKED RADIO. 
I manage to add the background class but i can't remove it's background when Unchecked.

Here is the code i'm using:

http://jsfiddle.net/ceWbW

Anyway to remove the background class after radio is unchecked ? I did not manage to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("td input:not(:checked)")` binds the event only to unchecked elements.

Bind it to all `td input` elements and use `this.checked` inside the callback to access the checked state.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ceWbW/5/

```
$("td input").change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var td = $this.parent();
    // un-green all columns which contain a radio element from the same group
    td.siblings().filter(function() {
        return !!$(this).find('input[name="'+$this.attr('name')+'"]:radio').length;
    }).removeClass('green');
    // green the current column in case the radiobox is enabled
    if(this.checked) {
        td.addClass('green');
    }
});
```